# Role of input resistance in LM384 Audio Power Amplifier

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, analog, circuit-design

let's consider the LM384 Audio Power Amplifier ([here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm384.pdf) the datasheet)

[image]

Can you explain me why is there the 150k resistance? It lowers the device input impedance, which is not good for a voltage amplifier.

Comment: This is an audio amplifier, not some highly sensitive op-amp. Why would you need more then 150K? Input signals are expected to come from a pre-amp which can easily drive 150K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It provides a path for the DC bias current to the input transistor so that the signal can be AC coupled with a capacitor.

Note that in the application diagram (fig 13 onwards in the data sheet) the two inputs can be connected to ground - it is not required to provide a bias voltage.

The value of the resistance, 150k, is high enough that it does not have any significant affect on the circuit operation.

Answer (score 1):

> It lowers the device input impedance, which is not good for a voltage
>   amplifier.

Firstly it’s an audio amplifier and any input impedance above 10 kohm is generally accepted as being fine except when used as an input stage for a guitar amplifier (which it shouldn’t be).

And, because it’s an audio amp that drives a speaker, having both inputs lightly DC biased will likely mean that on application of power, the speaker cone won’t make a popping sound. The “pop” is usually regarded as giving too much power to the speaker and potentially damaging it.